# Is there a way to set `LOCK=NONE` when doing a ALTER TABLE via an alembic migration?

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb, alembic

I would like to enforce that my migration doesn't lock a table.

In plain SQL I would use `ALTER ONLINE TABLE ...` or `ALTER TABLE x ADD COLUMN (...), LOCK=NONE`.

I can't find a way to replicate this with alembic using `op.add_column`.

Comment: Something like [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/compiler.html#dialect-specific-compilation-rules) with [CreateColumn](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CreateColumn).

Answer (score 0):

First note [ADD COLUMN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations-with-the-inplace-alter-algorithm/#alter-table-add-column) cannot be LOCK=NONE for Auto-increment.

```
SET SESSION alter_algorithm='INSTANT';
```

Might be a workable alternative. Ensure you have a MariaDB-10.6.9+ version per [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations-with-the-instant-alter-algorithm/).

Comment: I read that as saying it can be none *unless* it's auto increment.  But I've never tried, I just do `alter online ...`

Comment: oops, yes that's right.